# Summing Set values in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a set of Tuples and I'd like to get sum of it's values integer part. But when I apply this code it returns 1, when 3 is expected. I suppose that it's because result of the `map` function also returns a `Set` and duplicate results are eliminated.

```scala
object Main:

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val pairs = Set(("one", 1), ("two", 1), ("three", 1))
    val sum = pairs.map(pair => pair._2).sum
    println(sum) //returns 1
  }
```

My expectations are based on how such things work in Java. Set has distinct elements, but Stream doesn't until `distinct()` or `.collect(toSet())` are used. According to this the result is 3 as expected.

```java
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;

import java.util.Set;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        var pairs = Set.of(Pair.of("one", 1), Pair.of("two", 1), Pair.of("three", 1));
        var sum = pairs.stream()
                .map(Pair::getRight)
                .reduce(0, Integer::sum);
        System.out.println(sum); //returns 3
    }
}
```

My current assumptions on how to achieve such result (3) are:

1. Convert `Set` to `List`, but it seems not to be a good solution:

```scala
 val sum = List.from(pairs).map(pair => pair._2).sum
```

2. Use `foldLeft`:

```scala
val sum = set.foldLeft(0)((a, b) => a + b._2)
```

But maybe there are more convinient methods?

Comment: `set.iterator.map(_._2).sum`

Comment: Well, because a `Stream` is not a `Set` it behaves differently from a `Set`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`iterator`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/Set.html#iterator:Iterator%5BA%5D) or [`view`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/Set.html#view:scala.collection.View%5BA%5D) to get required collection representation:

```scala
val sum = pairs.iterator.map(_._2).sum
```